# Mail System module replacement?

Tags: emails

We recently updated Drupal Core to 7.26. Since that update Mailsystem doesn't work correctly. We've had to remove it from our site.

The error message we recieve is:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_52d3_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28): SELECT DISTINCT registry.name AS name, registry.filename AS filename FROM {registry} registry WHERE (type=:type AND ( filename like :filename OR name like :name )) ; Array ( [:type] => class [:name] => %MailSystem [:filename] => %.mail.% ) in mailsystem_get_classes() (line 282 of /sites/all/modules/contrib/mailsystem/mailsystem.module).
>   The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Any suggestions for a fix or replacement module?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions which can help:

- Check permissions of temporary folder
- create .htaccess file in temporary, files folders with this content:

.htaccess:

```
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

// [this options recently added to Drupal system](https://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003).

Comment: Permission are good in the tmp folder and the .htaccess file already had that content

Comment: @BrianP what says FileSystem configuration and system status?